# Ads Actions Stats purchase and other values

Tags: laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I want to fetch keys from facebook using their graph Api. Currently i am being able to fetch keys that were pretty straightforward in graph api console like frequency , reach etc. Keys like **purchase**, **Adds to cart** are not available in the graph api console and their documentation isnt very explanatory. Most of these keys are not returning any value in facebook's ads manager as well.
It would be really helpful if anyone can explain:

- When these metrics will be available ?
- I have seen a tool qwaya and it copies all the columns that facebook provides. How are they doing it ?
- What actions are to be performed on my ad so i can see any changes in
  those values ( PURCHASE , ADDS TO CART etc )

Another side note : I was using facebook-ads-sdk but now they have changed its name to business-sdk